# Simulating combined keystrokes not working?

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I want to simulate "cmd + k" keystorke in finder so that it can open "Connect to server window". But it is not working. I am new to objective C so can anyone help me. I tried below code but don't know why it is not working.

```
CGEventSourceRef src = 
CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateHIDSystemState);

CGEventRef cmdd = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, 0x37, true);
CGEventRef cmdu = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, 0x37, false);
CGEventRef k_d = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, 0x4F, true);
CGEventRef k_u = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, 0x4F, false);

CGEventSetFlags(k_d, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand);
CGEventSetFlags(k_u, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand);

CGEventTapLocation loc = kCGHIDEventTap; // kCGSessionEventTap also works
CGEventPost(loc, cmdd);
CGEventPost(loc, k_d);
CGEventPost(loc, k_u);
CGEventPost(loc, cmdu);

CFRelease(cmdd);
CFRelease(cmdu);
CFRelease(k_d);
CFRelease(k_u);
CFRelease(src);
```

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i have written small apple script and then calling the same inside cocoa, Please try below:-

```
NSBundle *def=[NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *path=[def pathForResource:@"openServer" ofType:@"scpt"];
NSAppleScript *appleScript=[[NSAppleScript alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:nil];
[appleScript executeAndReturnError:nil];
```

Below is the applescript file whose name is openServer.scpt

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "k" using command down
    end tell
end tell
```